# OpenVPN client unable to connect to obfsproxy

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, socks-proxy

I've set up my VPN server and client all working fine, but I'm trying to obfuscate the traffic with obfsproxy according to [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/TrafficObfuscation) guide, however it is not working for me on my elementaryOS-based pc.

The error that is returned to me is:

`Thu Feb 19 23:33:48 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.2 i686-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Thu Feb 19 23:33:48 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Thu Feb 19 23:33:48 2015 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:10194 [nonblock]
Thu Feb 19 23:33:48 2015 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:10194
Thu Feb 19 23:33:53 2015 socks_handshake: TCP port read timeout expired: Operation now in progress (errno=115)
Thu Feb 19 23:33:53 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,init_instance] received, process restarting
Thu Feb 19 23:33:53 2015 Restart pause, 5 second(s)`

At first I suspected this of having to do with SOCKS4 vs 5 but even after force installing the obfsproxy 0.2.6 version it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you installed obfsproxy via apt-get you get a SOCKS4 server, if you install it via PIP you get SOCKS5, but I couldn't get either of them to work with OpenVPN